# Core data exception "Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Has anyone seen the source of this Core data exception? What coulds be the cause? Thanks

Core data will throw an exception but continue without any error

Printing the exception breakpoint:

```
(lldb) po *(id *)($esp + 4)
error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory
```

Exception is thrown when calling save from a child managed object context

```
__block NSError *error;
[backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [backgroundContext save:&error];
}];
```

Comment: Some frameworks use exceptions internally, which they catch and which don't indicate any problem in the calling code. Are you experiencing any problems that you suspect are related to this exception? If it continues without error, it's probably not something to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a constraint violation.  If you do a `po [$arg1 reason]` you should get `constraint validation failure` meaning that the uniqueness constraint on one of your objects has been violated.  How this is then handled will depend on your merge policy.